# What is the equivalent of Puppet's Roles/Profiles Pattern in Ansible?

Tags: design, clean-code

In order to prevent spaghetti code in Puppet I am applying the [Roles/Profiles pattern](https://puppet.com/presentations/designing-puppet-rolesprofiles-pattern). Now I am learning Ansible and I am concerned whether spaghetti code will occur like back in the days when I started with Puppet. What patterns could be applied in Ansible to prevent code duplication and spaghetti code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ansible has the concepts of roles and dependencies which can be used in conjunction to create a roles/profiles/components pattern as you do in Puppet. You could design your role as a component, as a profile or as a role. Probably you would need a naming convention structure to not get confused about the difference between them. If you want to build a webserver role (puppet pattern) you could have 5 roles (ansible roles), component-apache, component-mysql, profile-database, profile-webserver, role-webserver. The first 2 will be roles that installs and configure a generic apache/mysql software (you should find it at ansible-galaxy). The 2 profiles will add these 2 components as dependencies (in meta/) and specify what exactly your implementation is via vars or tasks (should I support virtualhost? My mysql profile will work as cluster?). In the end, you create the last role (ansible) which will work as a role (puppet pattern). It will add as dependencies your 2 profiles (profile-database, profile-webserver).

In the end, on your playbook, you just apply the role-webserver to the nodes specified.